# Loading data with null value left join

Tags: go, go-gorm

I was trying to left join with `Industry` and `Organization`, I need to select the `Organization` with all the `Industry` it is mapped too and along with not mapped `Industry`.

```
type Industry struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(255);column:name;not null;unique"`
}

type Organization struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(255);column:name;not null"`
}

type IndustryForOrganization struct {
    gorm.Model
    IndustryId     uint `gorm:"column:industryId;not null;"`
    OrganizationId uint `gorm:"column:organizationId;not null"`

    Organization organization.Organization `gorm:"foreignkey:organizationId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Industry     industry.Industry         `gorm:"foreignkey:industryId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}
```

Industry

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Software |
| 2 | BPO |
| 3 | Education |
| 4 | Food and processing |
| 5 | Automobile |

IndustryOrganization

| id | OrganizationId | IndustryId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

I need to generate the below output for the organisation id 1.

| OrganizationId | IndustryId | IndustryName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Software |
| null | 2 | BPO |
| 1 | 3 | Education |
| null | 4 | Food and processing |
| 1 | 5 | Automobile |

I have the query to the get the required output

```
SELECT industries.id, industries.name, industryForOrganization.organizationId  
 FROM  industries 
 LEFT JOIN industryForOrganization ON industries.id = industryForOrganization.industryId 
 AND industryForOrganization.organizationId = 1
```

but I want to implement the same using gorm. I tried to achieve with the below mentioned code but I could get the expected output. I not getting any value for `IndustryForOrganizationIndustry`

```
var industryForOrganization []*IndustryForOrganization
    err := r.db.Debug().
        Raw("SELECT industries.*, industryForOrganization.* FROM  industries LEFT JOIN industryForOrganization ON industries.id = industryForOrganization.industryId AND industryForOrganization.organizationId = ? ", organisationId).
        Scan(&industryForOrganization).Error
```

As I'm new to golang, it is little difficult to get the solution. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did u try? It would be nice if you provided minimal reproducible example

Comment: @rosmak I have updated with what I had tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will do exactly what you need:

```
var industryForOrganization []*IndustryForOrganization

err := db.Table("industries")
.Select("industries.*, industryForOrganization.*")
.Joins("left join industryForOrganization on industries.id = industryForOrganization.industryId AND industryForOrganization.organizationId = ?", organisationId)
.Scan(&industryForOrganization).Error
```

Comment: Thanks, but we are getting IndustryForOrganization.Industry zero value.

Comment: GORM generates exact SQL query that you asked for in question

Answer (score 0):

Zero values from the previous answer are received as that is a default for the 'IndustryForOrganization' model that you are trying to populate.

Adjusting the model to use pointers that can be null will solve the problem.

```
type IndustryForOrganization struct {
    gorm.Model
    IndustryId     *uint `gorm:"column:industryId"`
    OrganizationId *uint `gorm:"column:organizationId"`

    Organization *organization.Organization `gorm:"foreignkey:organizationId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Industry     *industry.Industry         `gorm:"foreignkey:industryId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}`
```